# akka-http. Represent Option values

Tags: scala, deserialization, akka-http

By default, akka-http deserialize empty string in json(*i.e. `{"some_key":""}`*) to `Some("")`.

How to make akka-http deserialize empty strings in all `Option[String]` types in all models of the App to `None`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Akka-http` uses `spray-json` by default, so all you need to do is override the default behaviour by providing a custom one. One easy way to get what you are looking for is here: (mixin this trait on all your models)

```
trait CustomJsonMarshalling {
  implicit object OptionFormat extends JsonFormat[Option[String]] {
    def write(str: Option[String]) = JsString(str.getOrElse(""))

    def read(str: JsValue) = {
      str match {
        case JsString(s) => if (s.isEmpty) None else Some(s)
        case _ => throw new DeserializationException("Expected non empty string")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Honestly SPRAY Json is very limited. I would suggest play-json if yo uare working with scala or jackson for java.

Comment: I don't have strong opinions about either (having used both), but `spray-json` has been there from the beginning and covers most general use cases and provides ways to customize as needed.